# Can't Remove Linux image which caused login loop

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uninstall

```
    sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'

un  linux-image                               <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic             4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic             4.15.0-47.50~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic             4.15.0-48.51~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic             4.15.0-50.54~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-51-generic             4.15.0-51.55~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic             4.15.0-52.56~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-54-generic             4.15.0-54.58~16.04.1      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic             4.15.0-55.60~16.04.2      amd64                     Signed kernel image generic
un  linux-image-4.15.0-58-generic             <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-45-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-47-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-48-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-50-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-52-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-54-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-55-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
un  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-58-generic    <none>                    <none>                    (no description available)
```

I tried remove and purge and autoremove

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.15.0-58-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.15.0-58-generic
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I'm currently logged in 4.15.0-55-generic. I tried to remove 4.15.0-58-generic which caused login loops. I tried to reboot again and I can only login 4.15.0-55.

Sometimes I get this error. I don't know how to go to this directory and check what's in it.
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic': Directory not empty

I also don't know why there are so many images.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) will help.

Comment: And maybe you have to run `sudo update-grub2 `

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue is because it is the latest version. I tried sudo update-grub 2 and I tried using synaptic manager. There was no option to uninstall it. So I  installed it and rebooted. I ran into the same issue again when trying to use 4.15.0-58 instead of 4.15.0-55. The login screen/graphics appears to be of different resolution for this version. After I enter my password, it tries to login and loops back to the login screen. I think there might be a bug with this version since I did make changes. Maybe, I should try to fix this issue instead of removing the linux image.